# What is the meaning of the ending of "Remote Control"?

Tags: remote-control

Near the end of the novella "Remote Control", Sankofa looks out over the shea tree farm and sees that:

> the alien? seeds have grown all over.

She then thinks to herself about the possibility that the biotechnology firm LifeGen would harvest the seeds and potentially replicate her remote control powers on an industrial scale. She then invokes her powers, and the seeds glow green in response...and that is the end of the novella.

What is it implied that she is doing? Is she about to use her powers to destroy the seeds, despite their general resistance to destruction, and their potential resistance to her abilities in particular? Is she about to make them sprout into alien trees? Is she going to try to kill everyone in the town or on the planet<sup>1</sup> to prevent the scenario she foresees from happening?

<sup>1: That might seem like an extreme hypothesis, but it has precedent in Okorafor's previous works.</sup>

Comment: She _really_ just likes the color green?

Comment: dang, I thought this was going to be about the classic John Ritter movie, but then realized that was called "Stay Tuned"...

Comment: I just finished the book had the same question as you. I suppose it is the writer's way of letting us interpret it as we want. It says "and this time she did it on purpose" she had used her power on purpose before, but not on a large scale. So, it could be that she is using her power on a large scale on purpose (to exterminate the planet maybe?). But Sankofa is not vindictive and she in not angry, so it does not make sense to me that her character would do this. So, I am left with a question as to what happened. It is frustrating, I have to say.